# crytal report count total records

Tags: crystal-reports

Im using query in crystal report like:

```
if({?User Name}) <>"ALL"
then 
{COMN_USER_RESP_LINK_T.APPL_USER_NAME}={?User Name}
else
{COMN_USER_RESP_LINK_T.APPL_USER_NAME} ={COMN_USER_RESP_LINK_T.APPL_USER_NAME}
and
{COMN_USER_RESP_LINK_T.ENABLED}="Y"
```

this is actual query in sql:

```
SELECT
             C.APPL_USER_NAME,
             A.RESP_NAME,
             B.MENU_NAME,
             B.DESCRIPTION,
             B.MODULE_NAME,
             C.APPL_RESP
    FROM  COMN_RESPONSIBILITY_T A,
         COMN_RESP_MENU_LINK_T B,
         COMN_USER_RESP_LINK_T C 
    WHERE    A.COMP_CODE  = B.COMP_CODE
     AND    B.COMP_CODE  = C.COMP_CODE
     AND    C.COMP_CODE  = A.COMP_CODE
     AND    A.RESP_NAME  = B.RESP
     AND    C.APPL_RESP  = A.RESP_NAME
     AND    B.ENABLED  = 'Y'
     AND    C.APPL_USER_NAME  = c.APPL_USER_NAME
            CASE @ACCT_CODE_FROM 
                WHEN 'ALL' THEN C.APPL_USER_NAME 
                ELSE @ACCT_CODE_FROM 
            END
    ORDER BY APPL_USER_NAME,
         RESP_NAME
```

I should select user name in parameter field(?user name), if  I select ALL then I have to show all records (`{COMN_USER_RESP_LINK_T.APPL_USER_NAME}`)

is the above query correct?

Comment: you should format that query...it's making me go blind.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably rephrase that as something like:

```
SELECT C.APPL_USER_NAME, A.RESP_NAME, B.MENU_NAME, B.DESCRIPTION, 
    B.MODULE_NAME, C.APPL_RESP 
FROM COMN_RESPONSIBILITY_T A 
    INNER JOIN COMN_RESP_MENU_LINK_T B ON A.COMP_CODE = B.COMP_CODE 
        AND A.RESP_NAME = B.RESP
    INNER JOIN COMN_USER_RESP_LINK_T C ON B.COMP_CODE = C.COMP_CODE
        AND C.APPL_RESP = A.RESP_NAME 
WHERE ((@ACCT_CODE_FROM = 'ALL') AND (B.ENABLED = 'Y')) 
    OR (C.APPL_USER_NAME = @ACCT_CODE_FROM) 
ORDER BY APPL_USER_NAME, RESP_NAME
```

This gets you the details for either:

- when ALL is selected, all accounts that are enabled; or
- just the user code entered

Comment: give solution in crystal report (query)

Answer (score 0):

i don't read your code because it is very dirty!  but i think you can use SelectionFormula in crystal report. Certainly you can set it in code :

`crystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula ="(({?User Name}= 'ALL') AND ({B.ENABLED} = 'Y')) 
    OR ({C.APPL_USER_NAME} = @ACCT_CODE_FROM)"`

Comment: I could have -1 your answer, but spared you. If you are posting an answer you can "think/guess" thats the answer. For guesses theres comment